# SQLLite Open Helper - column doesnt exist

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a problem with SQLlite DB in my android app. I have DatabaseHelper class, as you can see bellow. And i am calling simple insert in an activity. But i am getting exception table tvSeries has no column named last_episode_id. I almost looks like it wont create a table ? But i cant see a problem.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tvSeries";
private static final String TVSERIE_TABLE_NAME = "tvSeries";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_LAST_ID = "last_episode_id";
private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_episode_name";
private static final String TVSERIE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TVSERIE_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_LAST_ID + "INTEGER, " +
                KEY_LAST_NAME + "TEXT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT);";

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TVSERIE_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TVSERIE_TABLE_NAME);

    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
}

public long createRecord(TvSerie serie){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, serie.getId());
    values.put(KEY_NAME, serie.getName());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_ID, serie.getLastEpisodeId());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, serie.getLastEpisodeName());

    // insert row
   long id = db.insert(TVSERIE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    return id;
}




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        TvSerie tvSerieTest = new TvSerie();
        tvSerieTest.setName("Test");
        tvSerieTest.setId(1);

        DatabaseHelper db  ;
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db.getWritableDatabase();
        db.createRecord(tvSerieTest);
 }
```

Comment: Uninstall the app, or go into Settings for your app and clear its data. Then, try running the app again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
> KEY_LAST_ID + "INTEGER, " +
> KEY_LAST_NAME + "TEXT, " +
> ```

You need whitespace between your column names and their types.

After fixing that, [make sure the database schema gets updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run).